# Connecting to servers issue

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I always play on Minecraft PE servers. Mostly Mineplex, but a couple of weeks after I updated 1.13, on the servers it always says “coming soon” or when I want to play with my friends it says “oops you disconnected for xbox restart world”. Even though I do restart it, it still says the same thing. I really want to play with my friends again.

Answer (score -3):

You know how there is a launch button at the bottom of the launch screen, at the top right corner there is a button that says launch options, click on that and click enable snapshots.